# Spring integration- Add check not to process inbound files older than 2 days and empty file

Tags: spring-integration

I need to add 2 checks for inbound channel adapter.

1. Should not process empty files
   2.Poller should not pick the files older than 3 days.

Above is the configuration used for inbound channel, but no idea how to add checks not to process empty/older files for poller,. need help on this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: code:
<integration:channel id="inputChannel"/>`
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="fileIn" directory="${inputdir}" channel="inputChannel">
 <integration:poller fixed-rate="1200" />
 <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter/>
 <integration:chain id="FilechainId" input-channel="inputChannel">
  <integraion:header-enricher>
   <integration:header name="originalpayload" expression="payload"/>
   <integraion:header-enricher/>
  `` <int-file:file-to-string-transform/>
   <integration:service-activator ref="myClass" method="execute"/>
   <integration:chain/>

Comment: Please, consider to edit your question with that code snippet to be readable. The comment is not OK for so big code to let us digest.

Comment: In commented section Spring configurations only I think we should add some filter it should not the files older than x days. I believe the controller code not required to add because controller will start after file picked up from inbound cannel